# Angular 2 & Jasmine - Testing if/else with @Inject

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular2-services, karma-coverage

I am trying to test and coverage the statements if/else with @Inject. But I only can coverage one of then.

env.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { WindowService } from './window.service';

@Injectable()
export class EnvService {
  properties: any;
  private _serviceUrl: string;

  constructor(@Inject(WindowService) private _window: any) {

    if (_window.properties['service.baseurl'] === '__serviceBaseUrl__') {
      this._serviceUrl = '/';
    } else {
      this._serviceUrl = _window.properties['service.baseurl'];
    }

    this.properties = {
      SERVICE_BASEURL: this._serviceUrl
    };
  }
}
```

In my test I have a "_window" variable where is declarated with the default values to test the if statement. Before to test the else statement I change the "_window" variable value.

env.service.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { EnvService } from './env.service';
import { WindowService } from './window.service';

describe('ConfigService', () => {
  let _window = {
    properties: {
        'service.baseurl': '__serviceBaseUrl__'
      }
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        EnvService,
        { provide: WindowService, useValue: _window }
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should ...', inject([EnvService], (service: EnvService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('properties has default values', () => {
    expect(_window.properties['service.baseurl']).toEqual('__serviceBaseUrl__');
  });

  it('properties has NOT default values', () => {
    _window = {
      properties: {
          'service.baseurl': 'http://wwww.google.com/'
        }
    };

    expect(_window.properties['service.baseurl']).toEqual('http://wwww.google.com/');
  });
});
```